# How to calculate centroid of vector of vectors using stl algorithms (accumulate and for_each)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, foreach, accumulate

I wrote program which generate 100 points in n dimension space and calculate centroid(geometric center). It works well but I need to write this part without using for loop, only using accumulate, for_each and arithmetic functors.

```
int dimensions = 2; 
int number_of_points = 100;
vector<vector<double>> cloud_A(number_of_points, vector<double>(dimensions, 0));
for_each(cloud_A.begin(), cloud_A.end(), RandomGenerator(5, 10));
vector<double> centroid_A(dimensions, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++){
    centroid_A[i] = accumulate(cloud_A.begin(), cloud_A.end(), 0.0, Sum(i));
}   
for_each(centroid_A.begin(), centroid_A.end(), Divide(number_of_points));
```

I stuck for few hours, wondering if it's even possible, my closest bet would be, if `cloud_A.begin()[count]` would work:

```
int count = 0;
for_each(centroid_A.begin(), centroid_A.end(), [&](double d){
    for_each(cloud_A.begin()[count], cloud_A.end()[count], [&](double punkt) {
        centroid_A[count]=accumulate(punkt.begin(), punkt.end(), 0.0, plus<double>()) << endl;
        });
        count++;
    });
```

Comment: Instead of holding a point's coordinates themselves in a vector, could it help to hold them in an `std::pair`, like this: `vector<pair<double, double>> cloud_A`? That might help you understand the iteration better...

Comment: But point can be multidimensional, it must be vector of vectors. Also I tried to access points from lambda by operator[], and like I said I said the best solution that come to my mind is 'cloud_A.begin()[count]' but I don't know how to make it work.